# Django Fixtures Error: Unknown application

Tags: python, django, fixtures

I have a project w/ multiple apps. I am attempting to use the `dumpdata` command to create a fixture for each app. Calling dumpdata on a given app seems to work well.

This prints the data to the console:

```
python manage.py dumpdata myapp
```

However, when I attempt to create a json file containing the dumped data:

```
python manage.py dumpdata apps/myapp/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

This error is thrown:

```
Error: Unknown application: apps/myapp/fixtures/initial_data
```

The fixtures dir already exists and I've tried multiple variations of the path to the json file. There is another coder on the project and we are working with the same source code. He does not appear to be running into the same issue though.

We are using Django 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give the correct syntax in your first snippet. The argument after `dumpdata` is an application, not a file.

If you want to save that output to a file, you use standard redirection:

```
python manage.py dumpdata myapp > apps/myapp/fixtures/initial_data.json
```